# JSON (String?) value prints with quotes (" ")

Tags: json, scala, play-json

```
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(input)
println(json)
```

prints:

> {"id":1,"command":"connect"}

```
val command = Json.stringify((json \ "command").get)
println(command)
```

prints:

> "connect"

what am I doing wrong that it prints **"connect"** (with quotes), rather than **connect**?

```
val command = (json \ "command").get.toString
println(command)
```

also prints:

> "connect"

```
command match {
case "connect" =>
    println("connected")
case _ =>
    println("unknown command")
```

prints:

> unknown command

Comment: `.get` is unsafe and so it's not recommended to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what am I doing wrong that it prints "connect" (with quotes), rather
>   than connect?

`(json \ "command").get` returns JsValue. When you call `Json.stringify` on JsValue object it gives string representation of JsValue object. `Json.stringify` does not convert JsValue object to String **type**. Using `Json.stringify` doesn't tantamount to type conversion, it's just a textual representation of the JsValue object.
From the [playframework doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson#Converting-from-a-JsValue) , the preferred way to convert from a JsValue to another type is by using its validate method. You will need something like as below:

```
val command = (json \ "command").validate[String].getOrElse("unknown command")

println(command) // prints connect without quotes
```

Comment: I got it working with **val command = (json \ "command").as[String]**, but you're right that I should use **validate**